# C: Printing linked list backwards

Tags: c, linked-list

Trying to print this list backwards

user inputs 10 characters, program prints out 10 characters in original order then in reverse order.

Thanks to you guys I figured out the problem why it wouldn't print in regular order, now I'm having some trouble getting it to print in reverse order..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define strsize 30

typedef struct member
{
    int number;
    char fname[strsize];
    struct member *next;
} RECORD;

RECORD* insert (RECORD *it);
RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j);

int main (void)
{
    int i;
    double result;
    RECORD *head, *p;
    head=NULL;
    result=10;

    for (i=1; i<=result; i++)
        head=insert (head);  
    print (head, result);

    return 0;

}

RECORD* insert (RECORD *it)
{

    RECORD *cur, *q; 
    int num;
    char junk;
    char first[strsize];
    printf("Enter a character:");
    scanf("%s", &first);

    cur=(RECORD *) malloc(sizeof(RECORD));

    strcpy(cur->fname, first);
    cur->next=NULL; 

    if (it==NULL)
        it=cur;
    else
    {
        q=it;
        while (q->next!=NULL)
            q=q->next;
        q->next=cur;
    }

    return (it);
}

RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j)
{
    RECORD *cur;
    cur=it;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=j;i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", cur->fname);
        cur=cur->next;

        //my solution for printing it backwards..

        void print(node *it)
        {
            if(it!=NULL)
            {
                print(it->next);
                printf("%s-->",it->number);
            }
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could include specifically what the problem is. In other words, instead of saying "I'm having trouble getting it to print in reverse order", consider explaining what exactly is going wrong. For instance: "It's only printing the first 2 characters" or "I tried reversing the linked list, but I'm getting the characters in a random order".

Comment: So what's wrong with it exactly?  Your `print()` function looks fine to me.

Comment: whoops, sorry. in void print it's giving me the errorerror: expected ')' before '*' token

Answer (score 2):

You have several "things" going by the name `print`

- a prototype: `RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j);`
- a call, inside `main`: `print (head, result);`
- a function definition: `RECORD* print(RECORD *it, int j) {`
- a nested function definition: `void print(node *it) {`

The first three are coherent, but the last one is just plain wrong.

Also
Standard C does not allow nested functions.
The type `node` is not defined.
You still need to work on your indentation :)

Comment: how would I go around that nested function?

Comment: First give it a different name; then move it out (cut/paste) of the enclosing function. If needed adjust code and you're ready for more fun :)

Comment: still having trouble haha, i wasn't meant to program!